# DataGrid drag/drop is not firing drop event when using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, drag-and-drop, caliburn.micro

I have a datagrid defined in xaml as follow:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessInputImages" 
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
              IsHitTestVisible="True"  AllowDrop="True" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action ObjectDropped($eventargs)" >

....
 </DataGrid>
```

and in my code behind, I have:

```
   public void ObjectDropped(DragEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

But the event is not firing when I drop a directory from explorer into it.

Why it is not firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that xaml was wrong:

the correct syntax is:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="ProcessInputImages" 
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" RowHeaderWidth="0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True"  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="Cell"
          IsHitTestVisible="True"  AllowDrop="True" cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action ObjectDropped($eventargs)]" >
```

....

note ] at the end of cal:Message.Attach="[Event Drop] = [Action ObjectDropped($eventargs)] which was missing.